# Pandas grouping by and aggregating with respect to unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, unique

In pandas v 012, I have the dataframe below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,9),
                        'code' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                                    'two', 'three', 'one', 'two'],
                        'colour': ['black', 'white','white','white',
                                'black', 'black', 'white', 'white'],
                        'texture': ['soft', 'soft', 'hard','soft','hard',
                                            'hard','hard','hard'],
                        'shape': ['round', 'triangular', 'triangular','triangular','square',
                                            'triangular','round','triangular'],
                        'amount' : np.random.randn(8)},  columns= ['id','code','colour', 'texture', 'shape', 'amount'])
```

I can 'groupby' `code` as below:

```
c = df.groupby('code')
```

But, how can I get the unique `texture` occurences broken down with respect to `code`? I tried this which gives an error:

```
question = df.groupby('code').agg({'texture': pd.Series.unique}).reset_index()
#error: Must produce aggregated value
```

From `df` given above, I want the result to be  a dictionary, to be specific this one:

```
result = {'one':['soft','hard'], 'two':['hard'], 'three':['soft','hard']}
```

The size of my real `df` is quite large so I need the solution to be efficient / fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get a dictionary of unique values is by applying `pd.unique` to the `groupby` object:

```
>>> df.groupby('code')['texture'].apply(pd.unique).to_dict()
{'one': array(['hard', 'soft'], dtype=object),
 'three': array(['hard', 'soft'], dtype=object),
 'two': array(['hard'], dtype=object)}
```

In *newer* versions of pandas `unique` is a method of `groupby` objects and so the neater way is:

```
df.groupby("code")["texture"].unique()
```

Comment: thank you, the `apply` version actually worked but not the direct `unique()` version.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the OP was using an older version, even though it's right there in the first sentence. :-/